# My web app deploys in azure needs to point to a static ip address

Tags: c#, azure, web-services, host

I want to add something.com with a static IP to my hosts' file

```
( %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts )
```

How can I do this in Azure?

PS : I do not want to use azure VM - I just want to use a web app.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you want to add a hosts file entry like `1.1.1.1  www.something.com` in Azure. You can deploy an Azure VM then run the web app on the Azure VM. Add the desired entry to `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on the VM. Then it will run the web app like running on the local VM. Even though you do this, it will not be publicly accessed if you use a private DNS name.

Update

> Azure Web Apps is a service for hosting web applications, REST APIs,
>   and mobile back ends. You can develop in your favorite language, be it
>   .NET, .NET Core, Java, Ruby, Node.js, PHP, or Python. Applications run
>   and scale with ease on Windows-based environments.

It is not like a Virtual Machine which has a hosts file for DNS resolution. Also, we access the web app via DNS name instead of IP address. I think Azure Web app might have no such function to point to a static IP address as your expectation.